# Duplicate consumer metrics when concurrency is set to more than 1

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.8 and setting concurrency to n for my consumer and trying pause the  consumer instance/thread to after that thread/instance consumed a pre-defined no of records(10k in this case). And then I'm trying to capture the consumer metrics to understand how fast my consumer can consume and process the records.

For example, I've produced 50k messages onto a topic and setting concurrency to 5, adding trying to pause the consumer threads after it consumed 10k records. Now, when i try capture the consumer metrics, I'm getting duplicate values and not sure which is correct. So, can someone help me understand, how can i get the correct metrics of my consumer?

Here is my consumer code

```
public static ThreadLocal<Integer> consumedMessages = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer initialValue() {
            return Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
    };

    public static List<ConsumerMetrics> mtpConsumerMetricsList = new ArrayList<>();

    int messageCount =10000;


    @KafkaListener(id = "myConsumer", topics = "myTopic", concurrency = 5)
    public void listen(String in) {
        try {
            consumedMessages.set(consumedMessages.get().intValue() + 1);
            System.out.println(" ConsumerConsumedMessages " + consumedMessages.get());



            if (consumedMessages.get() == messageCount) {
                System.out.println("ATTENTION! ATTENTION! ATTENTION! Consumer Finished processing " + messageCount + " messages");

                ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) this.registry.getListenerContainer("myConsumer");

                if (concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr != null) {
                    concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr.pause();
                    System.out.println("Pausing of mtpConsumer is done at " + LocalDateTime.now());

                    List<KafkaMessageListenerContainer> list = concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr.getContainers();

                    System.out.println("Containers list size "+list.size());

                    List<ConsumerMetrics> consumerMetricsList = new ArrayList<>();

                    list.forEach(childContainer -> {
                        ConsumerMetrics consumerMetrics = new ConsumerMetrics();

                        logger.logDebug(String.format("Child Listener Id is %s and assigned partitions are %s ",
                                childContainer.getListenerId(),
                                childContainer.getAssignedPartitions()),
                                this.getClass());

                        populateAndPrintContainerMetrics(childContainer.metrics(), consumerMetrics);

                        if (!consumerMetrics.getRecordsConsumedRatePerSec()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("0.0") && !consumerMetrics.getTotalRecordsConsumed()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
                            consumerMetricsList.add(consumerMetrics);
                        }
                    });

                    mtpConsumerMetricsList.addAll(consumerMetricsList);
                } else {
                    logger.logErrMsg("ERROR! ERROR! ERROR! concurrentMsgLstnrCntnr for Id myConsumer is null",
                            this.getClass());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.logException(ex,
                    this.getClass());

        }
    }

    private void populateAndPrintContainerMetrics(Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics, ConsumerMetrics consumerMetrics) {
        metrics.entrySet()
                .forEach(entry -> {
                    String topLevelMaetricKey = entry.getKey();
                    consumerMetrics.setConsumerId(topLevelMaetricKey);
                    System.out.println("metrics map entry key is " + topLevelMaetricKey);
                    entry.getValue()
                            .entrySet()
                            .forEach(innerMapEntry -> {

                                String metricKey = innerMapEntry.getKey()
                                        .name();
                                String metricValue = String.valueOf(((Metric) innerMapEntry.getValue()).metricValue());
                                System.out.println(" metricKey is " + metricKey + " and metricValue is " + metricValue);

                                switch (metricKey) {
                                    case "records-consumed-rate":
                                        //The average number of records consumed per second
                                        consumerMetrics.setRecordsConsumedRatePerSec(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "records-consumed-total":
                                        //The total number of records consumed
                                        consumerMetrics.setTotalRecordsConsumed(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "request-size-avg":
                                        //The average size of requests sent
                                        consumerMetrics.setRequestSizeAvg(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "request-rate":
                                        //The number of requests sent per second
                                        consumerMetrics.setRequestRate(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "request-total":
                                        //The total number of requests sent
                                        consumerMetrics.setRequestTotal(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "fetch-rate":
                                        //The number of fetch requests per second
                                        consumerMetrics.setFetchRate(metricValue);
                                        break;

                                    case "fetch-total":
                                        //The total number of fetch requests
                                        consumerMetrics.setFetchTotal(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "fetch-latency-max":
                                        //The max time taken for any fetch request
                                        consumerMetrics.setFetchLatencyMax(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "records-per-request-avg":
                                        //The average number of records in each request for a topic
                                        consumerMetrics.setRecordsPerRequestAvg(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "assigned-partitions":
                                        //The number of partitions currently assigned to this consumer
                                        consumerMetrics.setAssignedPartitions(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                    case "records-lag-max":
                                        //The max lag of the partition
                                        consumerMetrics.setRecordsLagMax(metricValue);
                                        break;
                                }
                            });

                });
    }
```

Here is the result of the consumer metrics and you can clearly see more than one result is coming for the same thread:

```
consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-0 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 68.71762342742362 and totalRecordsConsumed is 8715.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-1 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 154.52282723584165 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9064.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-2 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 150.11590645667144 and totalRecordsConsumed is 8807.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-3 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 164.1384476565027 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9641.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-4 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 166.65247526438583 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9786.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-0 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 68.71762342742362 and totalRecordsConsumed is 8715.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-1 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 154.5070230465021 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9064.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-2 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 150.10055561236663 and totalRecordsConsumed is 8807.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-3 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 164.16919252120016 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9641.0

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-4 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 166.63828627865 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9786.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-0 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 68.52444038373686 and totalRecordsConsumed is 8715.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-1 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 170.05067510118016 and totalRecordsConsumed is 10000.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-2 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 170.0420003740924 and totalRecordsConsumed is 10000.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-3 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 163.85390642261086 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9641.0 

consumerId is producer-perf-test-topic32-ClientId-4 and recordsConsumedRatePerSec is 166.39178412935914 and totalRecordsConsumed is 9786.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking - you are running that code on all 5 consumer threads so you will get 5x5 = 25 lines (each one rendered 5 times).

Here, I only 5 lines, regardless which technique I use to get the metrics:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62452699Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62452699Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so62452699", topics = "so62452699", concurrency = "5")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so62452699").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
        return args -> {

            // this one's more concise 

            registry.getListenerContainer("so62452699").metrics().forEach((clientId, metrics) -> {
                System.out.println(clientId + ": " + metrics);
            });

            // or

            ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) registry.getListenerContainer("so62452699"))
                    .getContainers()
                    .forEach(container -> System.out.println(container.metrics()));
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. just curious to know, why is it getting 5 lines for each thread ?

Comment: Because you have 5 threads (concurrency) and you are iterating over all 5 child containers on each thread. `list.forEach(childContainer -> {...});`,